# How can i click kendo grid first row on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo grid `id = AddressID`. when page load how can i click the first row automatically?

i tried the code below but no luck

```
var grid = $("#AddressGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.select("tr:eq(1)");
```

i tried this it selects the row but i want to  trigger click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#AddressGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.select(grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(1)").click());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data hasn't been loaded yet, there is nothing to [`select`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/select). You will have to specify the [`dataBound`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) event and add you own handler.

**Update:** The [`change`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/change) event fires whenever a row is selected either programatically or by the user's mouse.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
      read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
    },
    pageSize: 20
  },
  height: 550,
  sortable: true,
  selectable: "row",
  pageable: { refresh: true, pageSizes: true, buttonCount: 5 },
  columns: [
    { field: "ContactName", title: "Contact Name" },
    { field: "ContactTitle", title: "Contact Title" },
    { field: "CompanyName", title: "Company Name" },
    { field: "Country" }
  ],
  change: onChange,
  dataBound: onDataBind // Callback handler
});

function onDataBind(e) {
  this.select("tr:eq(0)"); // this === $("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
}

function onChange(arg) {
  const selected = [...this.select()].pop(); // multi-select is off
  const record = this.dataItem(selected);
  console.log(record.ContactName);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4em !important; }
.as-console .as-console-row .as-console-row-code,
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { font-size: smaller; }

.k-grid { font-size: 0.667rem; }
.k-grid td { line-height: 1.667rem; }
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.915/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.915/styles/kendo.materialblack.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.915/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to click on the first row?

Comment: @kukamuk You can always add your own click event to the grid, but the proper way to listen for a change event is to utilize the frameworks' own events. I updated the response above.

Comment: Thank you. thats my issue where to add the click event on the first row on your solution

Comment: @kukamuk Why are you calling `click` on the row? How are you assigning the listener outside of Kendo?